# Spring MVC: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Intended functionality of the website: You enter two numbers, and you get a page which says Result: (the sum of the two numbers)

When I delete my example-servlet.xml file to use a configuration class, I get the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource 
[/WEB-INF/example-servlet.xml]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext 
resource [/WEB-INF/example-servlet.xml]
```

AddController.java:

```
package com.example.demo1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
public class AddController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t2"));
        int k = i + j;

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("result.jsp");
        mv.addObject("k", k);
        return mv;

    }
}
```

SpringConfig.java:

```
package com.example.demo1;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.example.demo1"})
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

WebInit.java:

```
package com.example.demo1;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="t1"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result is <%=request.getAttribute("k")%></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My project structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVyI0.png)

Comment: Remove your `web.xml`. The `WebInit` is the replacement for the `web.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hi, this solved my problem. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The exception message is meanning full, your spring webapplication does not found the servlet configuration file `/WEB-INF/example-servlet.xml`.

Seek where you must put your servlet file in any webapp.
You will find the answer yourself as soon as you try to work like that.

If you want to autodetect some configuration, in Spring Boot configuration, we use that kind of annotations :

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.bendathierry.web")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
public class YourWebApplicationMainClass {
    // Beans definitions...
}
```

And, of course, bad way to display data : `<%=request.getAttribute("k")%>`.
You should find another way to go in order to **escape any user provided datas** nor calculated ones, because sometimes calculated ones are just leaks if you do not follow strict protectives programming rules.

Comment: Hi, I understand it hasn't found example-servlet.html, but I want to use the annotation version instead using @Configuration in my SpringConfig class. I deleted the example-servlet.xml so SpringConfig is used instead but its not working

Comment: Ok, I have added an example config for Spring Boot webapplication.

Comment: Hi, thank alot for your help. Will this be similar if i’m not using spring boot. (i’m not using spring boot because i’m still learning the basics of spring core and mvc) Also do you reccomend any books or tutorials to learn protective programming rules

Comment: Ok. Check "Spring in Action" | "Spring MVC and Web Flow" will be some good starting points for your actual path. Old books but very smart and precious informations inside.

For protective programming rules, you can seek inside some websites first, life the OWASP one, it is always up-to-date for programming with security in mind.
You can have a small powerpoint about security in programming readable on SlideShare : https://www.slideshare.net/OWASPKerala/java-secure-codingpractices.

Comment: Il definitely check them out, thanks alot